# Map to List , List to Map

Tags: list, class, dictionary, dart

```
class Person {
  int? id;
  String? name;
  int? age;
  Person(id, name, age) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '{$id,$name,$age}'.toString();
  }

  static String PersonNameAge(name, age) {
    name = name;
    age = age;
    return ('{$name,$age}');
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) {
  var per1 = Person(1, 'Mark', 15);
  var per2 = Person(2, 'Jack', 24);
  var list = [];
  list.add(per1);
  list.add(per2);
  print(list);

  var map1 = {};
  list.forEach((element) {
    map1[element.name] = element.age;
  });
  print(map1);

  var list1 = [];
  map1.forEach((name, age) => list1.add(Person.PersonNameAge(name, age)));
  print(list1);

  var map2 = {};
  list1.forEach((element) {
    map2[element.name] = element.age;
  });
  print(map2);
}
```

I'm new to Dart. Basically trying to convert Map to List and then Back to Map. Using the same logic but somehow it give me an error only on the last map2 section. Wanted to know what's the logical error in the map2 section .The foll is the error code:
Unhandled exception
Nosuchmethoderror: Class String has no instance getter name.
"

Comment: You're adding `Person.PersonNameAge(...)` to `list1`. That function returns a string. Then you try to do `.name` and `.age` on the elements of `list1`, which are strings.
If you declared `list1` as `var list1 = <Person>[];`, you'd catch the problem earlier.

Comment: Thanks. How should I return PersonNameAge as List ? May be that would solve the last map2 problem ! If I could get code only for the method PersonNameAge !

Comment: '''
[{1,Mark,15}, {2,Jack,24}]
{Mark: 15, Jack: 24}
[{Mark,15}, {Jack,24}]
Unhandled exception:
NoSuchMethodError: Class 'String' has no instance getter 'name'.
Receiver: "{Mark,15}"
Tried calling: name
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:54:5)
#1      main.<anonymous closure>

'''
This is the error I get

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do differently. The `PersonNameAge` method returns a string, and if that's what you want, it's doing fine. If you want it to return a person, make it call the `Person` constructor (with some `id`, don't know what you want for that).

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained that. Basically I want map2 to recognise list1 as a List and not String. So map2 method should be able to print out key : value pairs, that has been picked from list1.

Comment: Basically I want map2 to recognize list1 as a List and not String. So map2 method should be able to print out key : value pairs, that has been picked from list1. Thanks

Comment: But `list1` *is* a list of strings because you add only strings to it. So, try adding something else to it.